# Select value of one column if a separate column does not meet a certain condition

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like

```
player:string | team:string | position:string

jim  | packers  | qb

jack | patriots | rb

mark | texans   | te

tim  | packers  | wr
```

I want to select the team names that don't have a player that plays the "qb" position. In this case the results would ouput the team names patriots and texans. Below is what I currently have.

```
select distinct team
from Players
where position <> 'qb'
group by team
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `<> 'qb'` for each of the groups you form, so it can't be in the normal `where` clause, as this applies to the entire table. I would write this with a subquery:

```
select distinct team
from Players
where team not in (
    select team
    from Players
    where position = 'qb'
);
```